# QComboBox doesn't receive focus

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox, setfocus

I have a dialog with several widgets. I set tab order for all of them but QComboBox never receives focus.
I tried to set focus via setFocus() but even in that case it is not highlighted.
How to set focus to widget?

[image]

Comment: Did you set focus policy for it?

Comment: @ariaman5 Yes didn't help

Comment: Please review your question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Setting the QComboBox focusPolicy (via designer or code) to **StrongFocus** will allow it to receive both Click and Tab focus and process keyboard events.  [Qt QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop)